# StreamReader on NetworkStream not reading line

Tags: c#, networking, streamreader, streamwriter, networkstream

I'm trying to make a class for easy Client/Server connections. Inside this class is a Server-Side Client, but it won't pick up things written to the server NetworkStream.
In case you're wondering, I intend to have all data go through the server program before sending it out to the Client, so I need something to process all the data on the NetworkStream (Hence Server-Side Client). Here's my Class:

```
public class ConnectionServer
{
    public readonly IPAddress ServerIP;
    public readonly IPAddress LocalIP;
    public readonly int Port;
    private TcpListener ServerIn;
    private Socket ServerSocket;
    private TcpClient ServerSideClient;
    private NetworkStream NetStream;
    public StreamReader ServerInput;
    public StreamWriter ServerOutput;

    public ConnectionServer(int port)
    {
        try
        {
            Port = port;
            ServerIP = IPAddress.Parse(NetHelper.GetPublicIP());
            LocalIP = IPAddress.Parse(NetHelper.GetLocalIP());

            ServerIn = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Port);
            ServerIn.Start();                
            Console.WriteLine("Server Started At: " + ServerIP.ToString() + ":" + Convert.ToString(Port));
            ServerSideClient = new TcpClient("localhost", Port);
            ServerSocket = ServerIn.AcceptSocket();
            Console.WriteLine("Server-Side Client Socket Accepted.");
            NetStream = ServerSideClient.GetStream();
            ServerInput = new StreamReader(NetStream);
            ServerOutput = new StreamWriter(NetStream);
            ServerOutput.AutoFlush = true;
            Console.WriteLine("All Streams Initialized.");
            ServerOutput.WriteLine("Testing Server-Side Client.");                
            Console.WriteLine("Test Message Sent.");
            Console.WriteLine(ServerInput.ReadLine());
        }

        finally
        {

        }
    }

    ~ConnectionServer()
    {
        ServerInput.Dispose();
        ServerSideClient.Close();
    }

}
```

It doesn't write anything on `Console.WriteLine(ServerInput.ReadLine());`. I can't figure out why it won't pick up the message off the stream.
Help please?

Comment: What data do you send? Does it end with a newline?

Comment: `ServerSocket` is one client that connected to you.  Try reading from that with `.Read()`.  `ServerSideClient` is just a loop-back that you probably don't need.  (and probably hides any real outside connections)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that you're trying to use the same stream for reading and writing. `NetStream` is the input stream--the data from the client. If you want to write to the socket, you need to create a stream from the socket.

As it's written, you're writing to the client stream. You need to write to the server stream.

What I don't understand is why you're using `TcpClient` on the client side, and raw sockets on the server side after creating a `TcpListener`. You'd be better off using [AcceptTcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclient.aspx). Then you could write to that client's stream and read from the other stream.

To create a `NetworkStream` from the socket, use the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.aspx). I strongly suggest, though, that you switch to `AcceptTcpClient` instead.

Comment: So how would I create a stream from the socket? (I'm NEW to C# Networking)

Comment: I tried both and it didn't work for me... but then again, this is my first attempt at C# networking, so it only makes sense that 1. It fails, 2. It's sloppily put together. I'll try again from scratch, but this time I'll use `AcceptTcpClient()` and keeping other advice in mind. Thanks for your help, and I'll update if I have any future problems.